# Polynomial ring ideal. Show that $(f) \cap R_N = (0) \iff f \notin R_N$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have a polynomial ring $R = K[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ and $N \subset \{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$. Define $R_N = K[x_i:x_i\notin N]$. If $f\not= 0$, show $(f) \cap R_N = (0) \iff f \notin R_N$.

So my entire argument hinges that $f \in R_{N^c}$ and clearly $f\in (f)$, but $f \not= 0$, so the intersection must be $(0)$ since $0 \in R_N$. I m not sure how to do the other direction. They look similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f\not\in R_N$, then $f$ involves some variable $x_i\not\in N$.  The idea is then to show that every nonzero multiple of $f$ involves $x_i$, and hence is not in $R_N$.  To show this, you can look at the terms of $f$ that contain the highest power of $x_i$ and look at what happens when you multiply $f$ by any nonzero element of $R$.

(By the way, it's not true that $f\not\in R_N$ implies $f\in R_{N^c}$.  For instance, if $n=2$ and $N=\{x_1\}$, then $x_1+x_2$ is in neither $R_N$ nor $R_{N^c}$.)

Comment: so if you multiply $f$ by any nonzero element of $R$, you get a mixed polynomial, so you end up in $R$ again.